# Vaadin RTL support, get current direction

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I need to add RTL languages support to my application. I know how to set the direction to RTL:

```
UI.getCurrent().setDirection(Direction.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
```

but I also need to programmatically get this value in order to do some changes in the code.

How to get current `Direction` value in the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smells like a missing API, but for now, due to the async nature of `executeJs`, you might consider the following:

```
public void fetchPageDirection(SerializableConsumer<Direction> callback) {
    UI.getCurrent().getPage()
            .executeJs("return document.dir")
            .then(String.class, dir -> {
                Direction direction = getDirectionByClientName(dir);
                callback.accept(direction);
            });
}

private Direction getDirectionByClientName(String directionClientName) {
    return Arrays.stream(Direction.values())
            .filter(direction -> direction.getClientName().equals(directionClientName))
            .findFirst().orElse(Direction.LEFT_TO_RIGHT); // Default to LTR
}
```

After [this PR](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/15598) is merged and released, you can just use the API with the same name from `Page` instance:

```
UI.getCurrent().getPage().fetchPageDirection(direction -> {
    doSomethingWithDirection(direction);
});
```